# How can I hide MDI taskbar in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, mdi

I'm working on a project with MDI based UI. When I maximize an MDI child this bar (might be called MDI taskbar, not sure about that) appears. How do I hide it? I found a forum post showing a picture of it:

[image]

I can't find more about it on google, maybe because I don't know it's real name. I also didn't find a corresponding property in visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot hide it, it is an essential UI widget for MDI applications.  There's no way the user could close or restore a maximized MDI child window without it.

If you routinely maximize the MDI child then MDI just isn't the correct windowing model to use.  You might as well swap between UserControls in a normal window.

Comment: Well, that might work. And if it's the only solution, I'll have to do it. Thanks.